# What is the REST API rate limit for a standard Azure Search service?

Tags: powershell, azure-cognitive-search

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps that is creating 36 search indexes on a standard Azure Search Service that has a max of 50.

I am using a Powershell script that reads json files in a repo to create the search indexes using the REST API directly.

First I delete all indexes and then I create them again. (to cater for any changes in the json files stored in the repo)

It seems to be able to run for about 25 REST API calls before I get an error of:

```
(503) Server Unavailable. You are sending too many requests. Please try again later.
```

Even if I insert a delay of 4 seconds between each REST API call *(that either deletes or creates an index)* I still get the same error.

Is there anything special I need to do? Are the limits REST API call rate documented anywhere? ( I thought [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity), but sadly no.)

The Powershell script fragment is:  *($indexFiles is a list of the json files to apply)*

```powershell
$headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"
             "api-key" = $SearchAPIKey }

$indexesUrl = "https://$SearchSiteName.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=$SearchAPIVersion"

Write-Host "Applying the following $($indexFiles.count) index files: "

$indexFiles | ForEach-Object {  $indexData = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -raw
                                $filename = $_.Name
                                try
                                {
                                    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $APICallDelay
                                    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $indexesUrl -Headers $headers -Body $indexData
                                    if ($response.StatusCode -eq 201)
                                    {
                                        Write-Host "- $filename applied"
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Write-Error "Issues with creating index $filename with Url $indexesUrl. Status code returned was $($response.StatusCode). Msg: $($response.StatusDescription)"
                                    }
                                 }
                                 catch 
                                 {
                                    $summaryMsg = $_.Exception.Message
                                    $detailed = $_.ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json 
                                    $detailedMsg = $detailed.error.message
                                    Write-Error "Error with creating index $filename. $summaryMsg. Detailed error: $detailedMsg"
                                 }
                             }
```

If anyone can offer any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One workaround I have discovered is to only call the REST API 20 times, and then pause for _two minutes_ then trigger another 20 REST API calls and repeat. While this does work, the slowness is rather annoying. Hope there is a better way of handling this.

Comment: Have been told of the current limits to Azure Search Services:

* Create index  (POST) can be called up to 12 times per minute
* Update index (PUT) can be called up to 360 times per minute
* Delete index can be called up to 12 times per minute
* Get index can be called up to 600 times per minute
* List indexes can be called up to 300 times per minute

So currently, we have no choice but to put in `Start-Sleep -Minutes 2` in our code if we have more than 12 indexes to deploy at once. :(

Answer (score 3):

Have been told of the current limits to Azure Search Services:

- Create index (POST) can be called up to 12 times per minute
- Update index (PUT) can be called up to 360 times per minute
- Delete index can be called up to 12 times per minute
- Get index can be called up to 600 times per minute
- List indexes can be called up to 300 times per minute

So currently, we have no choice but to put in `Start-Sleep -Minutes 2` in our code if we have more than 12 indexes to deploy at once. :(